# Setting default column width for the "Workbooks.Add" function using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

In one of my codes, I'm automatically generating new workbooks. I need the column width to essentially be double whatever the default is (8.43 I assume).

Microsoft's workaround is to create an Excel template file, however that would require Admin privileges which I do not want to use as this file will be shared with non-admin users.

I'm looking for a code similar to this:

```
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 4
```

Wherein it sets the default number of sheets in any new workbook I create to 4. Is there something equivalent for column widths? I cannot seem to find it.

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't the code that generates workbooks just cycle all sheets in the generated workbook and set the width as needed? Relying on, and hijacking application-wide settings for this doesn't strike me as a good idea.

Comment: Why would you need admin privileges to create a template sheet?

Comment: To paste the template sheet into the correct directory. However I agree with Mathieu, will just use the .AutoFit function on certain columns. Not a perfect solution, but it would be too tedious to try and code the exact column widths for each cells that wouldn't display correctly otherwise..